# How to fix my CSS button transitioning only to the right and bottom direction and making it transition in all directions?

Tags: html, css, button, css-transitions

I'm looking for a way to transition the Orange button in all four directions,
not just the right and bottom directions if anyone can assist me with
the code.

```css
div {
          position: relative;
         left: 90px;
          top: 24px;
          border-radius: 25px;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
          background-color: Orange;
          padding: 20px; 
          width: 170px;
          height: 48px;
          transition: width 1s, height 1s, transform 1s; /* I want it to transition to the top and left directions */
        }
        
        
        div:hover {
          width: 255px;
          height: 72px;
        }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `transform` and `scale` , then with `transform-origin` you can change direction when transition.

```css
div {
          position: relative;
         left: 200px;
          top: 100px;
          border-radius: 25px;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
          background-color: Orange;
          padding: 20px; 
          width: 170px;
          height: 48px;
          transition: transform 1s;
          transform-origin: center;
        }
        
        
        div:hover {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: If the answer solves your problem. I'm glad you accepted my answer.